# (PHP) Mac issue: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function cleanArray() on null in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles

Tags: php, macos, null, macos-sierra, osx-yosemite

I get the following error message when sending a POST method to the server.

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function cleanArray() on null in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/Tremory/server/Login.php:36 Stack trace: #0
```

So it can not find the function from the class. This problem only occurs on Mac with OS: Sierra and works fine on Yosemite and Ubuntu. 
Any tips would be appreciated!

Comment: You need to share the code about Login.php, around the line 36.

Comment: ^ Debug why Line 36 has a null value rather than an object that contains the cleanArray() method.

Comment: noone can really answer that with the information provided. WAGs : running the wrong apache, running the wrong php, running the right php with missing modules. ps : php cli IS PROBABLY NOT the same as php/apache.